# How to print the JIT compilation messages for all the methods get compiled to native code of a given class

Tags: jvm, jit

I know I could use `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions` along with `-XX:CompileCommand=print,*TheGivenClass.TheGivenMethod'` to output the log for `TheGivenMethod` of the class: `TheGivenClass` when it is compiled into native code by JIT.

But what if I would like JVM to output the messages for any method of `TheGivenClass` as long as those methods get compiled into native code? thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "JIT compilation messages" you mean the generated assembly code for all methods of the given class, use the following syntax:

```
-XX:CompileCommand=print,org.pkg.TheGivenClass::*
```